# How to change the name of variables when adding more than one line plot

Tags: python, plotly

I have created a two line plot chart with Plotly and when showlegend=True, the name of the variables are Trace 0 and Trace 1. How can I change manually  the name of these variables?

I show below the code and the output.

```
# add line / trace 1 to fig_linee2
    fig_linee2 = go.Figure()
    fig_linee2.add_trace(go.Scatter(
    x=Deaths_wihing_28_days2["date"],
    y=Deaths_wihing_28_days2['newDeaths28DaysByDeathDate'],

    marker=dict(
        color="blue"
    ),
    showlegend=True
))

# add line / trace 2 to fig_linee2

    fig_linee2.add_trace(go.Scatter(
    x=patients_adm2["date"],
    y=patients_adm2["newAdmissions"],

    marker=dict(
        color="green"
    ),
    showlegend=True))

    fig_linee2.update_layout(
    height=400,
    title=dict(
        text='<b>Death people and admitted by COVID</b>', 
        x=0.5,
        y=0.95,
        font=dict(
            family="Arial",
            size=20,
            color='#000000'
        )
    ),
    xaxis_title="<b>Selected date</b>",
    yaxis_title='<b>Number of people</b>',
    font=dict(
        family="Courier New, Monospace",
        size=12,
        color='#000000'),
        
)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the "name" parameter to `go.Scatter(x=.., y=...,name=..., ...)`

See [Manual Labelling with Graph Objects in the doc](https://plotly.com/python/figure-labels/)